# How do I return Spark RDD partition values without a local iterator?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, iterator, rdd

I'm learning Spark and its parallelism that relates to RDD partition distributions. I have a 4 CPU machine hence I have 4 units of parallelism. To return the members of partition index "0" I couldn't find a way to return this partition without forcing the RDD to use a localIterator.

I'm used to spark being quite terse. Is there a more concise way to filter an RDD by partition? The following two methods work, but it seems clumsy.

```
scala> val data = 1 to 20
data: scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive = Range(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20)

scala> val distData = sc.parallelize(data)
distData: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int] = ParallelCollectionRDD[75] at parallelize at <console>:26

scala> distData.mapPartitionsWithIndex{
   (index,it) => {
      it.toList.map(x => if (index == 0) (x)).iterator
   }
}.toLocalIterator.toList.filterNot(
   _.isInstanceOf[Unit]
)
res107: List[AnyVal] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> distData.mapPartitionsWithIndex{
   (index,it) => {
      it.toList.map(x => if (index == 0) (x)).iterator
   }
}.toLocalIterator.toList.filter(
   _ match{
      case x: Unit => false
      case x => true
   }
)
res108: List[AnyVal] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
distData.mapPartitionsWithIndex{ (index, it) => 
      if (index == 0) it else Array[Int]().iterator
}
```

You can return an empty iterator and it will work fine.

Comment: So I noticed that that returns an RDD not an Array. But by your statement, you stay in the RDD domain (Spark land), hence you keep parallelism so don't "take(5)" and go single threaded - is that right? `scala> distData.mapPartitionsWithIndex{ (index, it) => if (index == 0) it else Array[Int]().iterator }.take(5)
res24: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`

Comment: You should try your best to perform operations by using RDDs so that you can scale your app easily.